# TFS 2010 Build setup permissions issue

Tags: build, tfs, permissions, tfsbuild

I'm looking to try to set up a build on TFS 2010 (stuck on it for now) and I'm getting the following permissions error when running my build:

> Failed to create directory [my output location]. User [service
>   account] needs write permissions to the path.

[image]

However, on the server, I am running TFS build service as my service account:

[image]

And in windows explorer, the service account is listed as having full control of the TFS_Builds directory:

[image]

I even restarted the TFS build server to make sure that wasn't an issue.

What am I screwing up / missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the issue here was using an output directory of \WebDev\E$\TFS_Builds.

On a hunch, I:

- created a share called TFS_Builds
- associated the proper permissions
- updated the output location to \WebDev\TFS_Builds.

This resolved the issue.